# ORDER BY date multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with my users and a table with the people who they're following, I also have the table with their status updates in. I need the statuses in time order. The only way I can think of doing it is by getting the people they're following and then one by one get their statuses which means it's only in time order for the single person.  Eg.

Tyler - Having a great time at the party. Time: 1PM
Tyler - Good morning everyone. Time: 10AM
Ben - What's everyone up to? Time: 2PM

Edit ----------

User table
[image: Users table]
Status table
[image: Status table]
Followers table
[image: Followers table]

User 1 is follow user 2.

Comment: can you show the data structure of your table instead?

Comment: Try using joins. You can get everything in one query.

Comment: do you want us to guess your table schema?

Comment: what is your problem? what do you want? please clarify.

Comment: Edited to show the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to use a join.

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT b.name, a.status, a.datetime FROM statuses a JOIN users b ON a.userid = b.id WHERE a.userid IN (SELECT c.userid FROM people c WHERE c.follower = :followerid) ORDER BY a.datetime
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this does exactly. I've never used joins before. Thanks.

Comment: Basically I am taking your 3 tables, joining them together by their id's with foreign keys, and filtering the results (the where) by another select clause. Although this is really outside the scope of a question like this. If you don't understand Sql Joins, you need to go read up on them or this will never make any sense. Here is a link to get you started - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: It's not that I don't understand them, it's just I've never used them.
Thanks.